# How to update custom field expando values for all users?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have one boolean custom field expando values for each user.
On certain events I want to update that field.

Currently the below code inside my hook works fine:

```
for (User user : users) {
    user.getExpandoBridge().setAttribute("myfield", false);
}
```

And I have tried below code but it wont work:

```
ExpandoTable expandoTable = ExpandoTableLocalServiceUtil.getTable(companyId);

ExpandoColumn expandoColumn =  ExpandoColumnLocalServiceUtil.getColumn(companyId, classNameId, expandoTable.getName(), "myfield");
ExpandoValueLocalServiceUtil.addValues(classNameId, expandoTable.getTableId(),expandoColumn.getColumnId(), classNameId, "myfield");
```

Comment: If the first code block works fine, why are your trying the second one? Which is not compiling anyway, because `addValues` with the given signature does not exist.

Comment: Have you created custom "myfield" using expando bridge?

Comment: Oh I understand now, is it that you want to change the custom-field values for all the Users at once instead of changing it for a single user at a time?

Answer (score 0):

The working code (e.g. the loop) that you give is the solution to your question. If you're looking for a single-SQL instruction to update all of the fields: Note that this might leave stale caches.

If you don't have a large number of users the loop shouldn't run long.

If, on the other hand, you have a significant amount of users, my assumption is that your portal is rather busy - and in this case I'd not like to clear the caches to make sure they're not stale on this single value. E.g. it's better to accept this operation to take a while. Your other option, clearing all caches after changing all values, would make sure to generate a huge performance drop as *everything* now needs to be loaded from DB.

Now if you told me that your loop runs for 2 days, I might have a different opinion, but your question does not sound like you're in big pain but it's rather about a preference to eliminate the loop.

Comment: Thank's for answering my question. Our product has 10000 user's so it'snot create much different.